# MacOS Mojave - Mail auto-appearing

Tags: macos, mac, email, gmail, apple-mail

I have a problem with Mail app. A few hours after quitting the app with Cmd+Q, the app starts up again suddenly, without being manually opened. It is connected with a Gmail account. Does anyone know if it can fixed?
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to deal with this is to keep the Mail app in a separate desktop or minimised. I believe the Mail app sometimes opens to either check mail or when mail is received.